# Convergence of a special sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence

There is a sequence: 
$$a_{n}=\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d+\frac{n}{d}}\cos(\ln(\frac{n}{d^{2}}))$$

Is this true that $a_{n}\rightarrow0$ ?

It seems that this sequence rather diverges.

I tried to prove its discrepancy by looking for special divergent subsequences, but i can't find.

I hope that someone will help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is an odd prime, then $$a_p=(-1)^{p+1}(\cos(\ln(p))+\cos(\ln(1/p))=2\cos(\ln(p)).$$ By Bertrand's postulate, the logarithms of consecutive primes are within $\ln(2)<\pi/4$ of each other.  It follows that every interval of the form $[N\pi/4,(N+1)\pi/4]$ for $N$ a positive integer contains a number of the form $\ln(p)$ for some prime $p$.  In particular, this means that $\cos(\ln(p))$ takes both values greater than $1/\sqrt{2}$ and values less than $-1/\sqrt{2}$ infinitely often.  It follows that the sequence $(a_p)$ cannot converge as $p$ ranges over the primes.

Comment: But what if i modify a little bit and put $a_{p}=2\cos(y\ln(p))$, for $y>0$ ?

Comment: Yes: the ratio between consecutive primes converges to $1$ and so the difference of their logarithms converges to $0$ and you can make a similar argument for any $y>0$.  This is a consequence of the prime number theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results for instance).